# Loop through user input in range

Tags: python, string, loops, range

I need to loop through an user input (regular text message with letters, numbers and other regular characters including whitespaces) in a range, for example:

My range is **read by 3 characters** from position (or index) 3:
`-m` is just a `switch` for console so it knows that it is a text message, so I want to ignore the -m + following white space and start considering the string and its size from H. So the string size will be 12 (5 + 1 + 6).

My attempt:

```
message = "-m Hello World!"

fragSize = 3
fragCount =0
start = 0
end = fragSize


if message.startswith('-m '):
    message = message[3:] #separates -m from the message

for index in range(1, len(message)):
    print('index[start:end]')
    start = end
    end += fragSize
```

**Message:**

`-m Hello world!`

**Output should be:**

```
Hel
lo_ (_ is a whitespace)
wor
ld!
```

Comment: What have you tried? Please show your code and explain what difficulties you are having.

Comment: I saw similar question today but I can find it. Use something like `text[i:i+3]` in `for i` loop.

Comment: Why downvote? Please explain

Comment: @febeks17, where is your attempt?

Comment: My attempt was wrong because I tried to use `for letter in string` as many tutorials say which is too simple and tutorials do not do more complicated examples and I also did not find a suitable example in here. That's why there is no attempt, so please remove downvote. Thank you

Comment: @febeks17, *My attempt was wrong because I tried to use for letter in string*, how is that an attempt at solving your problem?

Comment: @PadraicCunningham I have updated my question so please remove downvote

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
message = '-m Hello world!'
if message.startswith('-m '):
    message = message[3:]
while message!= '':
    print message[:3]
    message = message[3:]
```

Hel
lo
wor
ld!

Comment: Thanks. That's what I was looking for!

Comment: People are STUPID!! @febe

Answer (score -1):

You can use slice `[i:i+3]` with `for` loop to create it

```
text = 'Hello world!'

data = [text[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(text), 3)]

print(data)

['Hel', 'lo ', 'wor', 'ld!']
```

and the you can use `'\n'.join(data)` to print it as

```
Hel
lo_ (_ is a whitespace)
wor
ld!
```

You can recognize `-m` using `startswith()`

```
text = '-m Hello world!'

if text.startswith('-m '):
    text = text[3:] # remove "-m "

    data = [text[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(text), 3)]
    print('\n'.join(data))
```

Comment: And If I want to loop some more things in the for loop, how should I rewrite it? Because I am sending sockets which are divided into fragments using this for loop, but after the division, I need to send the fragment and then send another one until the entire message is sent.

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at argparse module(reference in end) for parsing input arguments from console.
Here is the snippet you can completely use, without worrying about snipping the input argument `switch`.

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Process message")
parser.add_argument('-m', dest='msg', type=str, help="Enter a message", required=True)
args = parser.parse_args()
x = args.msg

for p in range(0,len(x),3):
     snip = x[p:p+3]
     snip = snip.replace(' ', '_')
     print(snip)
```

You can use these commands to run the program
cd to dir in which file is saved.

this will show help text

```
python filename.py -h
```

this will run the program

```
python filename.py -m "Hello World!"
```

A documentation link to `argparse` https://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html